# Why doesn't Ethereum do double hashing like Bitcoin?

Tags: security, bitcoin, cryptography, keccak, hash-algorithm

Why doesn't Ethereum do double hashing like Bitcoin?  What are the facts or theories on the security of single Keccak-256 hashing like Ethereum, as compared to Bitcoin's double hashing with SHA2-256?  How about Bitcoin's use of a second different hash function (RIPEMD-160) in some cases?

Answer (score 3):

Saw the following from a recent paper published on February 19 2016.

> We have uncovered a worrying lack of defense-in-depth in Bitcoin. In
>   most cases, the failure of a single property in one cryptographic
>   primitive is as bad as multiple failures in several primitives at
>   once. For future versions of Bitcoin, we recommend including various
>   redundancies such as properly combined hash functions.

```
Cryptology ePrint Archive: Report 2016/167
On Bitcoin Security in the Presence of Broken Crypto Primitives
Ilias Giechaskiel and Cas Cremers and Kasper Rasmussen
https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/167
```

It sounds like double hashing in Bitcoin does not provide as much defense-in-depth as may be surmised.

Comment: Link to the paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/167.pdf

Comment: Double hashing is not for extra security. It is for doubling the computational time.